# Resource to understand compilation, loader, linker and process structure

Tags: c, assembly, compiler-construction, linker, loading

I would like to understand the overall process involved in compilation and execution of a C program . Specifically how C Source Files and Header Files compiled to object code and linked with libraries to generate an [ELF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) executable file and how the ELF is loaded in memory?
Also I would lik to read about the structure of an in memory process.
(I am not specifically looking for steps in compilation that I get from compiler books lik Aho, Ulman.)

What is the best resource (online/book) to understand this in good detail?

Comment: One place to start is http://programmers.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to learn about all of this recently. A book that details exactly what you are asking is:
[Computer Systems: A Programmer's Perspective](http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/0137133367/ref=pd_lpo_k2_dp_sr_2?pf_rd_p=103612307&pf_rd_s=lpo-top-stripe&pf_rd_t=201&pf_rd_i=013034074X&pf_rd_m=A3P5ROKL5A1OLE&pf_rd_r=1943JSQD0CQ8NH7TTY67). Specifically Chapter 7, which talks about the following topics:

- Compiler Drivers
- Static Linking
- Object Files
- Relocatable Object Files
- Symbols and Symbol Tables
- Symbol Resolution
- Relocation
- Executable Object Files
- Dynamic Linking with Shared Libraries
- Loading and Linking Shared Libraries from Applications
- Position-Independent Code (PIC)
- Tools for Manipulating Object Files

Comment: will look for it in the library. Thanks for suggesting.

Comment: @Steve "What's a library?" – You should ask that in a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Wikipedia is a good start. It has a number of links to other sites as well.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format

And the spec, of course: http://refspecs.freestandards.org/elf/elf.pdf